# Rails gem testing with Sorcery doesn't load user config in spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rubygems, sorcery

I'm trying to use Sorcery for testing a gem. The part of Sorcery initializer, responsible for User config, is not executed:

```
config.user_config do |user|
    user.username_attribute_names = [:email]
```

so I have an errors like:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause': SELECT  `users`.*
     FROM `users`  WHERE (username = 'user@app.com') LIMIT 1
```

I've turned off all extra sub modules

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.submodules = []
```

Never saw that error when testing normal app, not a gem.